# YUV buffer size not matching image size

Tags: java, android, android-camera2, yuv

I am currently using Android Camera2 API and decoding the frames through an ImageReader in a YUV_420_888 format. I managed to get everything working, all looks perfectly fine for both 320*240 and 640*480 sizes. But when I switch to 176*144, I get a weird result.

With this format and image size, I should have 38016 bytes in my buffer : 25344 in the Y plane and 6336 bytes in both the U and V planes. Instead, my buffer contains 39152 bytes. I get a correct size on the Y plane, but I get 6904 bytes on both the U and V planes, which results in green stripes across the image after an RGB conversion.

Any suggestion as to why this is happening ?

Comment: I have no Idea about this. But reading the question, I see the aspect ratio is 4:3 in first two examples. You should then try 176*132 to keep that. Otherwise, some distortions might happen I guess

Comment: I thought about that, but the issue is that the only formats natively supported by the camera in the YUV-420-888 format are the ones I mentionned. 176*132 is not a valid one for the Camera's ImageReader. Furthermore, the YUV-420-888 format specifies that for a N x M image size, the U and V planes should be of size (N/2) x (M/2), which is not the case here.

Comment: FWIW, I just ran into the same problem.  (Old LG phone.)  Except the size for my Y buffer is wrong: 27632.  (I didn't check the UV sizes -- just using greyscale for now.)  Like you, everything is fine with larger sizes.  Very odd!  Did you figure it out in the last 5 years?